# Найти и вырезать значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<span id="text">
img12433,id16423,text164423;img455325,id124363,text14623;img4553925,id12684363,text1467523;
</span>

var text = $('#text').text();

var key_replace = 'img12433,id16423,text164423'; //вырезать из var text
```

Строка содержит ключи, в каждом ключе три значения. Ключи разделены **;**, а значения **,**

**Задача:** Найти в строке ключ и удалить его (вырезать из строки)

**Вопрос:** Есть ключ **img12433,id16423,text164423**. Он находится в строке. Как составить регулярное выражения, которое вырежет этот ключ из строки?

Comment: `console.log(text.replace(key_replace + ';', ''));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ключ который вам нужно вырезать известен, можете его вырезать с помощью метода String.replace

```
newValue = text.replace(key_replace + ';', '');
```

newValue будет равна переменной text с вырезанной строкой из key_replace. Для составления регулярного выражения, нужно больше конкретики